# align flex items only in the 'second row' created by flex-wrap:wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I would like to align items (the number of items can vary) which are pushed into the second row by flex-wrap:wrap when the window size of the browser is resized below 900px to the right side.

[image: image to clarify what I want]

I used flex-wrap:wrap because the initial problem was, that the whole menu bar was too wide when the browser window got too small. 
 Wrap solved that problem but then the collapsing sub menu 'stick' behind the main elements of the menu bar (e.g. Link 3.1 behind Link 7)

[image: overlapping sub menu]

If anyone could provide a better solution than flex-wrap:wrap I would gladly appreciate that.
I tried to solve that issue with different versions of justify-content. But it either didn't work at all or the whole menu bar was affected.
 So the main question is: How to align only those items to the right side which are in the 'second flex row'?
I also created a pen: 
[but I cant poste more than two links, so I'm going to post the pen into the comments]

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // add JS-classes into the HTML-Tag
  $('html').addClass('js');

  // add classes for sub menus and sub menus toggle button
  $(".site-nav li > ul").parent('li').addClass('has-sub-menu');
  $(".site-nav li > ul").addClass('sub-menu');

  // create button for expand- und collapse the menu and render it into the header
  var create_toggle_nav_button = ['<div class="toggle-site-nav">Menu</div>'].join("");
  $("header").append(create_toggle_nav_button);

  // create button for expand- und collapse the sub menu  for mobile view and add them to all sub menus
  var create_sub_toggle_button = ['<span class="toggle-sub-menu"></span>'].join("");
  $(".has-sub-menu > a").after(create_sub_toggle_button);

  // define variables
  var $menu = $('.site-nav'),
    $toggle_nav = $('.toggle-site-nav'),
    $toggle_sub_menu = $('.toggle-sub-menu');

  // collapse and expand function of the main menu
  $toggle_nav.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $menu.slideToggle();
  });

  // collapse and expand function of the drop down menu for mobile view
  $toggle_sub_menu.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').slideToggle();
  });

  // display hidden elements again, when browserwindow is resized by user
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 900) {
      $('.site-nav').removeAttr('style');
      $('.sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
  });

  // collapse navigation automatically to the left, when it run out of the viewport
  $(".site-nav .has-sub-menu").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {

    var nav_element = $('ul:first', this);
    var element_offset = nav_element.offset();
    var element_offset_left = element_offset.left;
    var element_width = nav_element.width();
    var viewport_width = $(window).width();

    var element_in_viewport = (element_offset_left + element_width <= viewport_width);

    if (!element_in_viewport) {
      $(this).addClass('sub-left');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('sub-left');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  z-index: 9999;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  /* ? */
}

.site-nav {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.site-nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.site-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.site-nav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  /* text color of all */
  background: #5a595a;
  /* background color main nav Link 1 */
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.site-nav a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}

.js .site-nav {
  display: none;
}

.js .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}

.js .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

.js .has-sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}

.sub-menu li:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-menu a {
  background: #676567;
  /* background color menu 2.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a {
  background: #747274;
  /* background color menu 2.1.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}


/* toggles */

.toggle-site-nav {
  background: #5a595a;
  /* background color of menu button when resized */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  /* text color of the word menu in menu button when resized */
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.toggle-site-nav:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* mouseover color of menu button when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  align-content: center;
  right: 0em;
  top: 1.05em;
  /* hight of the borders */
  background: #817e81;
  /* backgound of annoying squares when resized */
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu.active {
  background: #DCDCDC;
  /* color of annoying square after clicking on it when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu:hover,
.toggle-sub-menu.active:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* mouseover of annoying squares when resized */
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
  .logo {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
  }
  .site-nav {
    width: auto;
    display: block !important;
  }
  .site-nav a {
    border: none;
  }
  .site-nav li {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .site-nav li:hover {
    background: rgba(52, 50, 52, 1);
    /* mouseover background color of all menu */
  }
  .has-sub-menu a {
    padding-right: 2em;
    /* check this value */
  }
  .has-sub-menu:after {
    /* check this for editing the stripes */
    display: flex;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
    top: 1.2em;
    right: 0;
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 25%;
    background: #817e81;
    /* color of stripes in main menu when it has submenu */
  }
  /* sub menu */
  .site-nav li:hover>.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: -25px;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sub-menu>a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:after {
    background: #817e81;
    /* color of stripes of Link 2.1 menu when it has submenu */
  }
  .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: 224px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .toggle-site-nav,
  .toggle-sub-menu {
    display: none !important;
  }
  /* navigations items, which collapse to the left */
  .sub-left>.sub-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
  }
  .site-nav .sub-menu .sub-left>.sub-menu {
    left: -275px;
  }
}

@media (max-width :800px) {
  .site-nav {
    z-index: 999999999999999999;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Here is the link to the pen:
https://codepen.io/undefined999/pen/MEwmOp

Comment: Is this the end result you want? https://codepen.io/solbreslin/pen/zEGPmX

Comment: @ovokuro yes, thats how I wanted it. How did you make that? you wizard?
do you maybe have an idea how to make that the sub sub menu (e.g. link 7.3.1 collapse to the left instead of to the right?
thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you for that hint, I added a snippet.

Comment: Why don't you just increase the z-index of the sub menu to appear on top?

Comment: @Obsidian I tried that but it didnt work and I couldn't figure out why not

Comment: @Obsidian can you help me to find the right spot for increasing the z-index to make it work like you said?
thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to `site-nav`:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .site-nav {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Then you can apply `margin-auto` to `ul`, and ajdust `justify-content` to `flex-end` (which will right align the `li`.

You may need to tweak `margin-top` property on `site-nav` to align things properly.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // add JS-classes into the HTML-Tag
  $('html').addClass('js');

  // add classes for sub menus and sub menus toggle button
  $(".site-nav li > ul").parent('li').addClass('has-sub-menu');
  $(".site-nav li > ul").addClass('sub-menu');

  // create button for expand- und collapse the menu and render it into the header
  var create_toggle_nav_button = ['<div class="toggle-site-nav">Menu</div>'].join("");
  $("header").append(create_toggle_nav_button);

  // create button for expand- und collapse the sub menu  for mobile view and add them to all sub menus
  var create_sub_toggle_button = ['<span class="toggle-sub-menu"></span>'].join("");
  $(".has-sub-menu > a").after(create_sub_toggle_button);

  // define variables
  var $menu = $('.site-nav'),
    $toggle_nav = $('.toggle-site-nav'),
    $toggle_sub_menu = $('.toggle-sub-menu');

  // collapse and expand function of the main menu
  $toggle_nav.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $menu.slideToggle();
  });

  // collapse and expand function of the drop down menu for mobile view
  $toggle_sub_menu.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').slideToggle();
  });

  // display hidden elements again, when browserwindow is resized by user
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 900) {
      $('.site-nav').removeAttr('style');
      $('.sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
  });

  // collapse navigation automatically to the left, when it run out of the viewport
  $(".site-nav .has-sub-menu").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {

    var nav_element = $('ul:first', this);
    var element_offset = nav_element.offset();
    var element_offset_left = element_offset.left;
    var element_width = nav_element.width();
    var viewport_width = $(window).width();

    var element_in_viewport = (element_offset_left + element_width <= viewport_width);

    if (!element_in_viewport) {
      $(this).addClass('sub-left');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('sub-left');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  z-index: 9999;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  /* ? */
}

.site-nav {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.site-nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
}

.site-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.site-nav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  /* text color of all */
  background: #5a595a;
  /* background color main nav Link 1 */
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.site-nav a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}

.js .site-nav {
  display: none;
}

.js .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}

.js .sub-menu .sub-menu {
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

.js .has-sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}

.sub-menu li:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.sub-menu a {
  background: #676567;
  /* background color menu 2.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a {
  background: #747274;
  /* background color menu 2.1.1 only */
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* mouseover color Link 1 and Link 1.1 */
}


/* toggles */

.toggle-site-nav {
  background: #5a595a;
  /* background color of menu button when resized */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  /* text color of the word menu in menu button when resized */
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.toggle-site-nav:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* mouseover color of menu button when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  align-content: center;
  right: 0em;
  top: 1.05em;
  /* hight of the borders */
  background: #817e81;
  /* backgound of annoying squares when resized */
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.js .toggle-sub-menu.active {
  background: #DCDCDC;
  /* color of annoying square after clicking on it when resized */
}

.toggle-sub-menu:hover,
.toggle-sub-menu.active:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* mouseover of annoying squares when resized */
}

@media screen and (min-width:900px) {
  .logo {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
  }
  .site-nav {
    width: auto;
    display: flex !important;
  }
  .site-nav a {
    border: none;
  }
  .site-nav li {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .site-nav li:hover {
    background: rgba(52, 50, 52, 1);
    /* mouseover background color of all menu */
  }
  .has-sub-menu a {
    padding-right: 2em;
    /* check this value */
  }
  .has-sub-menu:after {
    /* check this for editing the stripes */
    display: flex;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    align-content: center;
    top: 1.2em;
    right: 0;
    width: 0.5em;
    height: 25%;
    background: #817e81;
    /* color of stripes in main menu when it has submenu */
  }
  /* sub menu */
  .site-nav li:hover>.sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: -25px;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .sub-menu>a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:after {
    background: #817e81;
    /* color of stripes of Link 2.1 menu when it has submenu */
  }
  .has-sub-menu .has-sub-menu:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
    left: 224px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .toggle-site-nav,
  .toggle-sub-menu {
    display: none !important;
  }
  /* navigations items, which collapse to the left */
  .sub-left>.sub-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
  }
  .site-nav .sub-menu .sub-left>.sub-menu {
    left: -275px;
  }
}

@media (max-width :800px) {
  .site-nav {
    z-index: 999999999999999999;
    margin-top: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <nav class="site-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2.1.4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7.3.5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 7.5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/solbreslin/pen/zEGPmX)

Comment: thanks for your answer you mean here? 
     @media screen and (min-width:900px) {
    .logo { 
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    }
    .site-nav{ width:auto; display: flex !important; }

Comment: @undefined yep :)

Comment: thank you very much, ovokuro :) 
I really appreciate your help
I give you thumbs up but it didnt show because of my low reputation 
I try to implement your suggestions now

Comment: I build in your suggestions and the stick to the right side works :)
I tried it on my mobile and it look like this: https://imgur.com/a/N1sJi
Do you maybe have an idea how I can prevent the collapsing submenu from overflowing out of the page?
Thank you